# Use multiple dates in pd.date_range

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I have a range of dates in date column of dataframe. The dates are scattered eg 1st feb, 5th Feb, 11th feb etc.

I want to use pd.date_range with frequency one minute on every date in this column. So my start argument will be date and the end argument will be date  + datetime.timedelta(days=1).

I'm struggling with using apply function with this, can someone help me with it? or can I use some other function over here?

I don't want to use a for loop because the length of my dates will be HUGE.

I tried this :

`df.date.apply(lamda x : pd.date_range(start=df['date'],end = df['date']+datetime.timedelta(days=1),freq="1min"),axis =1)`

but I'm getting error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `x` in lambda function instead `df['date']` and remove `axis=1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2021-11-26', periods=3)})

print (df)
        date
0 2021-11-26
1 2021-11-27
2 2021-11-28

s = df['date'].apply(lambda x:pd.date_range(start=x,end=x+pd.Timedelta(days=1),freq="1min"))
print (s)
0    DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-26 00:00:00', '2021-11...
1    DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-27 00:00:00', '2021-11...
2    DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-28 00:00:00', '2021-11...
Name: date, dtype: object.Timedelta(days=1),freq="1min"))
```

Comment: I tried it but still getting error, here's my data and code:

 `market_time['date']

2020-02-03   2020-02-03
2020-02-07   2020-02-07
2020-02-10   2020-02-10
2020-02-11   2020-02-11
2020-02-12   2020-02-12
2020-02-13   2020-02-13
2020-02-14   2020-02-14
2020-02-17   2020-02-17
2020-02-18   2020-02-18
2020-02-19   2020-02-19
2020-02-20   2020-02-20
2020-02-24   2020-02-24
2020-02-25   2020-02-25

Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]`

`market_time['date'].apply(lamda x:pd.date_range(start=x ,end = x +pd.Timedelta(days=1),freq="1min"))
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @DevangB - there was typo, `lamda` need `lambda`